# Findbug ES_COMPARING_STRINGS_WITH_EQ not triggering if one string is member of parameter object

Tags: java, findbugs, spotbugs

```
public static void findbugDoesNotTrigger(List<String> object) {
    String string2 = "AnyString";

    if(object.get(0) == string2) {
        System.out.println("Does not matter at all");   
    }
}
```

Here I expected either ES_COMPARING_STRINGS_WITH_EQ or ES_COMPARING_PARAMETER_STRING_WITH_EQ to trigger but it did not. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You are a victim of a Java design principle called [Type Erasure](http://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure).

So, when FindBugs looks at your compiled code, it sees you compare an `Object` to a `String`, which might be correct as you might want to assert that they are the same object.

You might do the following to trigger the error:

```
public static void findbugDoesNotTrigger(List<String> object) {
    String string1 = object.get(0);
    String string2 = "AnyString";
    if(string1 == string2) {
        System.out.println("Does not matter at all");   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i Suspect if your code had been

```
if(string2 == object.get(0)) {
```

the rule would have fired.